# VMWare Fault Tolerant Benchmarks

Tags: vmware, fault-tolerance, esx

We are looking at deploying high availability VMs using VMWare Fault Tolerant. Has anyone got any real world benchmarks? I'm only after relative performance of running a VM conventionally in ESX v's running in FT mode.

I assume there must be some performance hit running in FT, but I can't find any benchmarks anywhere. We will be running multiple VMs and a database in this mode.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a quick look and found the following benchmark for FT: [FT Benchmark](https://blogs.vmware.com/performance/2009/08/comparing-fault-tolerance-performance-overhead-utilizing-vmmark-v111.html)

this does look to match my previous experience of using FT. This is however a technology that I no longer use due to its limitations with CPU and if one VM is corrupt so is the secondary.

Personally I find that for DB you are better running in Always-on modes.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I stumbled across that myself, but was hoping for something that wasn't done by VMWare (aka a sales pitch) to see some real world results.